# Event Store Summing Number of Expired Items using SQL

Tags: sql-server, query

I have the following table:

```
+---------+---------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| shop_id | card_id |      event       |   event_timestamp    |     card_expires     |
+---------+---------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|       1 |       1 | some event       | 2019-10-01T00:00:00z | 2019-10-10T00:00:00Z |
|       1 |       1 | some other event | 219-10-02T00:00:00Z  | 2019-10-10T00:00:00Z |
|       1 |       2 | an event         | 2019-10-03T00:00:00Z | 2019-10-29T00:00:00Z |
|       1 |       2 | another event    | 2019-10-04T00:00:00Z | 2019-10-29T00:00:00Z |
|       1 |       3 | foo event        | 2019-10-03T00:00:00Z | 2019-10-10T00:00:00Z |
|       1 |       3 | bar event        | 2019-10-04T00:00:00Z | 2019-10-10T00:00:00Z |
+---------+---------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

I'm trying to find the total number of expired cards for a `shop_id`. If we say that current timestamp is `2019-10-20T00:00:00Z` then card_id 1 and 2 will be expired.

Expected Result:

```
+---------+-------------------------+
| shop_id | number_of_expired_cards |
+---------+-------------------------+
|       1 |                       2 |
+---------+-------------------------+
```

Ive gone around in circles with INNER JOIN, CASE and GROUP BY. I can identify the cards that have expired but then when I try to sum them into the results table, I get bigger values than I need. Totally stuck ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT shop_id, COUNT(DISTINCT card_id) number_of_expired_cards 
FROM sourcetable
WHERE card_expires < GETDATE()
GROUP BY shop_id
```

Comment: ah thanks a lot! I knew i'd made a total mess of it and forgot some simple way to do it